# Cannot access custom CSS and JS files from server

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, tomcat

**The problem**

Server returns 404 NOT FOUND when it wants to access my static files: css and js

In the IntelliJ IDEA editor i have correct path as it shown on the picture
[image: Path to CSS is correct]

but when i access the page on login.jsp file browser drops the next message to console:

GET http://localhost:8087/static/css/actionForm.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

The same thing to custom js files, js and css files from CDN such as bootstrap are working fine, only custom files are not working

Some time ago i was work on this project and all was done well, but now i don't know why error happend.

**What i've tried**

I've tried to change relative path of project, was using asset method in src parameter, but nothing works. I saw some resolution with the server.js file, but think that answer not far.

My project structure with static directory expanded:

[image: Project structure]

The war was deployed fine, the structure is below, but server cannot access such file

[image: War structure]

My logs show this

```
2021-01-05 23:00:47 [DEBUG] DispatcherServlet:865 - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/static/css/actionForm.css]
2021-01-05 23:00:47 [DEBUG] RequestMappingHandlerMapping:304 - Looking up handler method for path /static/css/actionForm.css
2021-01-05 23:00:47 [DEBUG] RequestMappingHandlerMapping:314 - Did not find handler method for [/static/css/actionForm.css]
2021-01-05 23:00:47 [WARN ] PageNotFound:1147 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/static/css/actionForm.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

Comment: Did you try `../static/css/actionForm.css` ? Notice the `../` in front of the path.

Comment: What URL do you use in the browser to access `login.jsp`? How are you deploying to the server?

Comment: my index.jsp page redirects to login page, so at login.jsp i see `http://localhost:8087/`
. I'm deploying using maven

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by moving my `main.jsp` and `login.jsp` to `jsp` directory and removing spring from my project. Thank you for answers